# BrowserRouter won't pass history to component inside render

Tags: react-router-v4

The React router version is 4.
Here's the usage of `BrowserRouter` inside my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import browserHistory from 'history';
import {Tracker} from 'meteor/tracker';

import Signup from '../imports/ui/Signup';
import MyLink from '../imports/ui/MyLink';
import NotFound from '../imports/ui/NotFound';
import Login from '../imports/ui/Login';

const history = browserHistory.createBrowserHistory();

const unathenticatedPages = ['/', '/signup'];
const athenticatedPages = ['/mylink'];
const isLoggedIn = () => {
  return Meteor.userId() !== null;
};

const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch >
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => (isLoggedIn() ? <Redirect to="/mylink"/> : <Login/>)} />
      <Route path="/signup" render={() => (isLoggedIn() ? <Redirect to="/mylink"/> : <Signup/>)} />
      <Route path="/login" render={() => (isLoggedIn() ? <Redirect to="/mylink"/> : <Login/>)} />
      <Route path="/mylink" render={() => (!isLoggedIn() ? <Login/> : <MyLink history={history}/>)} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Tracker.autorun(() => {
  const isAuthenticated = !!Meteor.userId();
  console.log("isAuthenticated: ", isAuthenticated);

  const pathname = history.location.pathname;
  console.log("pathname: ", pathname);

  const isUnathenticatedPage = unathenticatedPages.includes(pathname);
  const isAthenticatedPage = athenticatedPages.includes(pathname);

  if (isLoggedIn() && isUnathenticatedPage) {
    history.replace('/mylink');
  } else if (!isLoggedIn() && isAthenticatedPage) {
    history.replace('/');
  }
});

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

The issue I'm having with this is that `BrowserRouter`'s `history` doesn't get passed to the rendered components when those are inside a `render()` like above. `this.props.history.replace('/notfound');` won't work inside the `MyLink` component. The `history` instance passed to the `MyLink` component doesn't seem to appear the same as the one `BrowserRouter` creates.
However inside the `NotFound` one `this.props.history.replace('/...');` would work as expected.

What would be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is to use history object from function params sent by `render()`

```js
<Route path="/mylink" render={({history}) => (!isLoggedIn() 
    ? <Login/> 
    : <MyLink history={history}/>)} 
/>
```

Comment: This is the only answer on this topic that actually shows an example of how to do this effectively. +1, solved my problem.